# Tesseract speed

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I've been working on a small application that uses OCR to read and store information in an accessible way. The application itself works fine and Tesseract is doing a good job, however, the other day I was messing around with Microsoft PowerToys and noticed they have integrated a OCR tool (https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/powertoys/text-extractor).

I can't find much information regarding how their implementation works behind the scenes, but it's seemingly hundreds of times faster than any result I'm getting from tesseract on the same sample images (tesseract takes 3-5sec while Text Extractor is almost instantaneous).

For my app tesseract is still the way to go since I can schedule a bunch of jobs at the same time, it was just interesting to me to see such stark differences in speed.

Since it piqued my interest it got me wondering if anyone had any insight regarding how they've managed to make it so fast?

Comment: Test-Extractor is based on Text-Grab which uses the [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.ocr?view=winrt-22621) to do the work (the latest is AFAIK closed-source so no-one can tell). Tesseract do not seems to be particularly optimised (at least not for speed). Besides, I do not think it makes use of devices like GPUs. Speed is not the only parameter of an OCR though. I wonder if Tesseract gives more accurate results.